# Better understanding of pipes

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork

While learning about pipes, by mistake, I wrote the following code

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    int p1[2];

    pid = fork();
    pipe(p1);

    if(pid==0)
    {
        dup(p1[0], 0);
        close(p1[1]);
        execv(abs_addr_of_some_bin , argv);
    }
    else
    {
        dup(p1[1] , 1);
        close(p1[0]);
        write(p1[1] , some_rand_text , size_of_text);
        wait(&status);
    }
}
```

The binary being executed has a `read(0 , buf , size)` statement, that reads from STDIN.

Well, the above code is obviously incorrect, as I have `fork()` before the `pipe()`. So when I try to output the `buf` in the other binary, it prints some random value that is different everytime I execute this file. 
What could be the reason behind this?

Also, if i correct my code (i.e call `pipe()` before `fork()`), there are certain things related to the working of the pipe that confuse me:

1. As the `p1` array will have different memory addresses for both processes( parent and child), how does the OS know that the other end of p1[0] (in the child) is p1[1] (in the parent)?
2. What kind of memory operations take place in this process?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `how does the OS know that the other end of p1[0] (in the child) is p1[1]`: a process have a structure in which there is the list of files and pipes opened. When you do a `fork`, the child receives the same pipes. Fork is a system function, available in the linux kernel (it's name is __sys_fork).

Comment: @Pierre - what makes you think fork() is only in linux, or that a person using the "unix" tag is specifically interested in linux

Comment: @Arlie Stephens: I never told that. There are at least in all POSIX OS. And for information, there is/was no kernel system call to `fork` in Windows. some compilers add an implementation of fork.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create the pipe after the fork but before! If you create it after then you are creating two unrelated pipes... As you need to share the same pipe for both processes, create it before forking.

You have *random values* because your pipes are not connected and something didn't really test the `read`s in your `exec`ed process.

About addresses. No `p1` has exactly the same address in the parent and the child! But these address are in different address spaces. Addresses a process manipulates are always relative to its given address space.

The fork duplicates address space of the parent process and built a strict copy of it for the child process.

Comment: Sorry, but didn't get this line : something didn't really test the `read`s in your `exec`ed process.?

Comment: You said you have garbage, as your pipes are not well connected, the `exec`ed command probably reads wrongly into the pipe... You didn't gave us all the code; we can only give some hints.